# Mallet IELE Compiler crashes without Uncaught Error

Tags: ethereum, erc20, smart-contract

I was able to get mallet running with the command ./mallet iele -d .

I created a simple contract that works in Remix but when I try to compile the contract using iele I get a ***Uncaught 'Compiler error: 0\nundefined'***

The contract below

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;

contract Inbox {

    string public message;

    function Inbox(string initialMessage) public {
        message = initialMessage;
    }

    function setMessage(string newMessage) public returns(string) {
        message = newMessage;
    }



}
```

[image]

Comment: Just a guess: Your `setMessage` function should return a string but it doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to get it running  as well, but I IELE its still in R&D.
I recommend following this tutorial instead.
https://youtu.be/p3ee19mJUOA